# Why Visual Studio Express edition doesn't see GhostDoc

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

I successfully installed GhostDoc to Visual Studio 2012 (Express Edition). Unfortunately, when I'm starting Visual Studio after installation, I don't see icon "Document this". I can't use Ctrl+Shift+D to document code and, if I click right button on name of class, I don't see "Document this". Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: This may be better answered by the GhostDoc folks.  Here's the link to their support forums: http://community.submain.com/

Comment: The problem was that Express editions of Visual Studio don't support Add-In extensibility - a Microsoft restriction.

Comment: @makcis add your comment as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Express Editions of Visual Studio only support extensions which have been especially approved by Microsoft for use in those editions. The only real cases where you can extend these editions is the following:

1. You can add new Project or Project Item templates, provided they are prepared without additional functionality.
2. You can install the NuGet Package Manager extension, which has special installation privileges for Express Editions starting in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I have the NuGet Package Manager extension. How can it help me?

Comment: @makcis It can't. It's completely unrelated to GhostDoc and only mentioned here so that I could provide a complete answer.